# Closing a mutex handle

Tags: c#, mutex, handle

I want to close a mutant handle to run an application in 2 windows.
The handle name is:

> \Sessions\3\BaseNamedObjects\Growtopia

I can close it in Process Hacker, but I can't figure out how to do it in C#.
I can close it by C# but its always different. Sometimes its 0x498, sometimes 0x49c and etc.

All code I got:

```
string path2 = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "handle.exe");
File.WriteAllBytes(path2, RubbyEngine.Properties.Resources.handle);
Process.Start(path2, "-c 498 -y -p " + pidLabel.Text);
```

The `-c 498 -y -p` are the arguments I use to close the handle, but its always different, and I can't change it on every launch.